# How to export and import PDF of form?

Tags: sitecore-forms

We have a client that has the following functionality on their existing site:
Content Editors can create / edit a form as required.
They can then click a check a box, within the form editor that allows users to have one of two options:

Firstly they can fill the form in as normal, filling the fields and moving to the next page.

Or

They can click a download button, this presents them with a modal box and a few simple form fields (Name, email etc taken from the first page of the form) and a further download button.
Clicking the download button generates a PDF based on the form, with the data from the modal box pre filled.

Each of the form fields is set as an editable field in the PDF, they can pass this PDF around the various departments to ensure that the information is correct.

Once complete they can then upload the completed form to the website, where the PDF is processed to create a form submission as if they had filled in the form normally.

I think that as Sitecore Forms are just a collection of items, I can see a way to generate the PDF correctly, but I don't know of a mechanism that I can use to take that data once completed and create a form submission from it?

Answer (score 0):

For the saving of the data you can make use of the `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IFormDataProvider` interface and call the `CreateEntry` method.

If you have any attachments you can make use of the `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IFileStorageProvider` to store them.